# Counting and grouping data that have the same value in several columns

Tags: python, dataframe, grouping, apply, counting

I have a hard time doing this particular task: from the data below I want to count the elements that are equal to 0 in all Degrees and group them. In other words, how many X1 have all of the three degrees equal to 0?

```
Element | Degree A | Degree B | Degree C |
.............................................
 X1 |         0          0          0 
 X1 |         1          1          0
 X1 |         0          0          0 
 X2 |         1          0          1
 X2 |         0          0          0
 X2 |         0          0          0
 X3 |         0          0          0  
 X3 |         1          1          0
 X3 |         0          1          0
```

This is the desired output:

```
    Element     All=0 counts
................................
    X1           2
    X2           2
    X3           1
```

This is what I have tried:

```
d1 = df.groupby(["Element"])["Degree A"].apply(lambda x: (x==0).sum())
```

I tried to add the other columns, but it doesn't work

```
d2 = df.groupby(["Element"])["Degree A"]&["Degree B"]&["Degree C"].apply(lambda x: (x==0).sum())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One reasonable way to do this is to make another column before the groupby:

```py
df['check'] = df['Degree A'] + df["Degree B"] + df['Degree C'] == 0

df.groupby(['Element'])['check'].sum()
```

which gives the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You can sum the 'Degree' like columns and check whether their result equals to 0 using `filter` + `sum(axis=1)` + `eq(0)`. This results in a `boolean` `series` which can be passed into [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) which will return dataframe of only the rows that summed to 0.

On this result you can use [`groupby.size()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) which will count the occurrence of each element:

```
df.loc[df.filter(like='Degree').sum(1).eq(0)]\
    .groupby('Element', as_index=False).size()

  Element  size
0      X1     2
1      X2     2
2      X3     1
```

Data sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Element': {0: 'X1',
  1: 'X1',
  2: 'X1',
  3: 'X2',
  4: 'X2',
  5: 'X2',
  6: 'X3',
  7: 'X3',
  8: 'X3'},
 'Degree A': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 0, 3: 1, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 1, 8: 0},
 'Degree B': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 1, 8: 1},
 'Degree C': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 1, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0}}
    )
```